# install package in python - firewall issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, linkedin-api

I'm trying to install linkedin libraries, but have problems with connection (due to some firewall restrictions) and I get an error:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install linkedin
Collecting linkedin
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connectio
n aborted.', error(10061, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))': /simple/linke
din/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connectio
n aborted.', error(10061, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))': /simple/linke
din/
Operation cancelled by user
```

Is there any chance to download linkedin libraries and install it locally? 
If yes, can you provide any hints?

I've downloaded package from : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-linkedin/4.0

Regards,
Pawel

Answer (score 0):

`pip` can install from downloaded file

```
pip install python-linkedin-4.0.tar.gz
```

Comment: It sill tries to download someting from the Internet

Comment: some modules require other modules - this need requests>=1.1.0, requests-oauthlib>=0.3, oauthlib>=0.6.2 / niektóre moduły dociągaja potrzebne im moduły

Comment: Add more explanation for the answer. Your answer is flagged as low-quality because of the length...